# Using Async-Await in Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, async-await, asyncsocket

In Stefen Toub's code [**Awaiting Socket Operations**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) : it doesn't mention about the usage of its **async** methods. I mean how the Server program will be calling the **async** methods using **await**? Ther isn't any **main**() also. Please elaborate over this. I tried creating a main() and calling the **SocketExtensions.ReceiveAsync(sock,awaitable);**

```
public static void Main(string[] str)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n<<<<<<<<<<<  Server is starting...  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 10100);
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    args.SetBuffer(new byte[0x100000], 0, 0x100000);
    var awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(args);
    while(true)
        SocketExtensions.ReceiveAsync(sock,awaitable);
}
```

But it didn't work for me.

Comment: What exactly 'didn't work'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stephen Toub's blog post is not a sockets tutorial; it's showing how to use custom awaitables to support extremely high-performance socket applications.

I recommend that you start with something like WebAPI or WCF and only use bare sockets if you *have* to. If you absolutely do need to use sockets, then I recommend that you first use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to wrap the `Begin`/`End` methods; this is slightly less efficient but an easier programming model. If performance tests indicate that your server isn't fast enough at this point, *then* you should use the custom awaiter approach from Stephen Toub's blog post.

The reason your server isn't working is because you're not listening nor accepting. I recommend you use WebAPI or WCF instead.